Multiple inheritance with more arguments than in the parent classes
I am having issues with multiple inheritance. The subbclass has more arguments than its parents classes and some of the arguments I want the first parentclass to handle and the rest I want the other parentclass to handle.
The subclass ElectricCar has 1 more argument than its parent classes but this argument is not unique for its class, so I don't want to duplicate code. I want the argument 'acceleration' to be handled by the Car class and the 'range' to be handled by the ElectricVehicle class. But as both Car and ElectricVehicle accepts only two arguments it does not work.
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.brand = brand


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, brand, acceleration):
        super().__init__(brand)
        self.acceleration = acceleration


class ElectricVehicle(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, brand, range):
        super().__init__(brand)
        self.range = range


class ElectricCar(Car, ElectricVehicle):
    def __init__(self, brand, acceleration, range):
        super().__init__(brand, acceleration, range)

I added **kwargs to all classes and I don't get the error anymore. I also specified each argument (brand=brand). I don't know if this fixes anything or if problems will occur later in the process because of this. Is there no other way to fix this? Here is the code when i added **kwargs:
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, brand, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.brand = brand


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, brand, acceleration, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(brand, **kwargs)
        self.acceleration = acceleration


class ElectricVehicle(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, brand, range, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(brand, **kwargs)
        self.range = range


class ElectricCar(Car, ElectricVehicle):
    def __init__(self, brand, acceleration, range, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(brand=brand, acceleration=acceleration, range=range, **kwargs)

Thanks in advance!
